# JS Promise - return result not another promise

Tags: javascript

This below is not working...
I don't want to return another promise, I want the script to be slow and single threaded and return YES or NO.
Is that possible?

```js
this.getToken = function() {
  if (typeof messaging == 'undefined') return false;
  
  return messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
   if (currentToken)
    return true;
   else
    return false;
  }).catch(err){
   return false;
  });
 };
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could give us a bit more context

Comment: That is not how promises work....

Comment: Your wording of the problem implies you don't know how to extract the primitive value from the returned promise. Try `...getToken().then(function(result) {  // here 'result' is true or false  })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises don't return values. Instead, you need to communicate with the parent thread via setting a variable in the parent thread's context. E.g.

```
this.getToken = null;

if (typeof messaging == 'undefined') this.getToken = false;

    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
        if (currentToken)
            this.getToken = true;
        else
            this.getToken = false;
    }).catch(err){
        this.getToken = false;
    });
};
```